# React Navigation 2: How to check previous scene and to disable tab change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a tab navigation. One of my tabs has a form and I would like to disable navigate event if my form data is not saved.

In ver.1, the `tabBarOnPress` method provides `previousScene`, `scene` and `jumpToIndex`, so I was able to check which scene I am leaving and to access its props.

Now in ver.2, the `tabBarOnPress` method provides the `navigation` props for the scene, but the previous scene prop is missing :/

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
        // Check the previous screen
        // If I am leaving the home screen and the user has unsaved data
        // disable tab navigation
        // else change to the pressed tab
    },
},
```

Also, I tried with the navigation event listeners but the `NAVIGATE` action is already dispatched:

```
props.navigation.addListener('willBlur', () => {
    // Disable tab switching;
}),
```

Simple snack: https://snack.expo.io/@hristoeftimov/handle-tab-changes-in-react-navigation-v2

Any solutions how to disable tab switching before leave a tab?

Comment: does this help? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/routers.html#blocking-navigation-actions

Comment: You can store the previous,  current screen with react-navigation `onNavigationStateChange` https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html. I'm not sure it will invoke after or before `tabBarOnPress`. You can debug that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a much simpler way, using the `getStateForAction`.

```
const defaultGetStateForAction = MainStack.router.getStateForAction;
MainStack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if (!state) {
        return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
    }

    if (
        action.type === NavigationActions.NAVIGATE
        && state.routes[state.index].key === 'HomeTab'
    ) {
        const tab = state.routes[state.index];
        const currentRoute = tab.routes[tab.index];
        const currentRouteParams = currentRoute.params;

        if (currentRouteParams && currentRouteParams.isNavigationDisabled) {
            return currentRouteParams.showConfirmationDialog(action);
        }
    }

    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
}
```

Every time when I switch between the tabs it jumps into `getStateForAction` where I can access the leaving tab (from `state`) and the next screen (from `action`).

So, when my action is `NAVIGATE` and the leaving screen/route is `HoneTab` I can change/disable the default state for action and to trigger `showConfirmationDialog()` - This is a function that I can set as a route parameter to my `HomeTab` screen.

Answer (score 0):

The `navigation` object contains the data you need, as it holds the navigation state prior to the navigation to the new tab. This navigation state has both the screen from which you're navigating and its params.

In order to get the state you can use the following function:

```
function getCurrentRoute(navState) {
  if (!navState) {
    return null;
  }
  const route = navState.routes[navState.index];

  if (route.routes) {
    return getCurrentRoute(route); // nested routes
  } else {
    return {
      name: route.routeName,
      params: { ...route.params }
    };
  }
}
```

So now you can use this function inside the onPress handler. Something like this:

```
navigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({ navigation, defaultHandler }) => {
        const currentRoute = getCurrentRoute(navigation.state);
        if (currentRoute.name !== 'Home' || !currentRoute.params.isNavigationDisabled) {
            defaultHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this means that you'll need to manage a navigation param called `isNavigationDisabled` in your Home screen by using `this.props.navigation.setParams` method.

Also, I hope I was correct with the screen name, if not just debug it.

Comment: Sounds good, but there is one problem. I can set a pram called `isNavigationDisabled` to my Home screen, but when I press on another tab and go into this `tabBarOnPress` I receive the state of the pressed tab, not of the leaving, so I cannot access the `isNavigationDisabled` property

Comment: @HristoEftimov `tabBarOnPress` is called before transition. Don't pass `isNavigationDisabled` in params, rather keep it in redux and set it in constructor of form. Then, don't call `defaultHandler` when `isNavigationDisabled` is set.